# Cloudant add on Heroku not working

Tags: heroku

I am trying to install cloudant on my vulcan based app. 
However when I try to add the free version of cloudant through the heroku addons I get the following error:

```
Could not communicate with vendor, please try again later
```

Want to confirm if this is a temporary vendor issue or is it something with my app?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, so probably broken on Cloudant's end

Comment: @marcgg I contacted the support, when I had the issue a few months back. They fixed it. Probably not working again, you should get in touch with the support team.

Answer (score 1):

I contacted Heroku support and was told Heroku is in the process of removing the add-on. I don't know any further details, but it looks like in order to have Cloudant work on Heroku you'll need to set the account up yourself.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like an error in the brokering between Heroku and Cloudant.  If you can file a ticket with support@cloudant.com (including account information and time of the failure) we can track it down on our side and see if there's action we can take.  Alternatively, you can always signup directly at cloudant.com as a short-term work around.